# JPA Summary entity or meta entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

I'm using JPA (With hibernate under the hood) and want to select out a bunch of data which summarises a set of real entities, so for instance a name, the name of a parent entity and a count of instances with that name.

In my entirely fictional example lets have an entity called Ticket, which has a parent entity named Category which itself has a parent entity called MetaCategory.

I want to retrieve a list of all categories, and display the parent metacategory name, the category name, and the count of tickets within that category.

I could just select all the tickets and shove them in  a hashset, keyed by category, but that feels quite inefficient.  What I'd ideally like to do is select out a list of an entirely new entity, that is not backed by any database table, but holds a MetaCategory, a Category and an integer of the count of Tickets...

Is this possible using JPA, specificaly using the `CriteriaBuilder`? Do I just have to select things out manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you absolutely need to use Criteria Queries, you can do it using Criteria Constructors and Selection items see [CriteriaQuer#multiSelect](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaQuery.html#multiselect(javax.persistence.criteria.Selection...))

You would have to use select the specific columns that you are interested in 
and get a Tuple or an Object array back from the query.

For instance, with a tuple it would be something like that (not tested at all) :

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> query = cb.createQuery(Integer.class);

Root<Category> r = query.from(Category.class);
Join<Category, Ticket> jT = r.join("tickets")
query.multiselect
(
 cb.construct(A.class, root.get("property1"), root.get("property2"),
 cb.construct(Ticket.class, jT.get("..."))
);
List<Tuple> result = query.getResultList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Hibernate you can either create a database view or a subselect. A view will be treated just like a table. To define a subselect using annotaions, try this:

```
@Entity
@Subselect("select item.name, max(bid.amount), count(*) "
    + "from item "
    + "join bid on bid.item_id = item.id "
    + "group by item.name")
@Synchronize( {"item", "bid"} ) //tables impacted
public class Summary {
   @Id
   public String getId() { return id; }
   ...
}
```

As taken from the [docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-class).